# How do I populate a table column based on the month input of 'login_at' column in an existing database in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-controller

I have an existing database which is already populated. I created a new column to store the month in which the data was populated.

How do I populate the 'month' column with data based on the `login_at` at column of each row?

[image]

I am able to populate the current inputs based on the current month like this

```
$login_time = Login::create(['user_id'=> auth('user')->user()->id, 'session_id' => session()->getId(), 'login_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(), 'login_ip'=> $request->getClientIp(), 'is_active'=> true, 'month'=> now()->month ]);
```

But I am unable to populate the other previous cells for month. How do I populate this column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Login::get()->each(function ($l) { 
   $l->month = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($l->login_at)->format('m');
   $l->save();
})
```